# Joomla forum not loading 404 - component not found

Tags: joomla, forum

Recently I made some changes to this websites menus and now the forum will no longer load, all the data is still there, but I cannot access the forum.

http://www.yumping-amok.com/index.php?Itemid=115

I get this error message:

```
404 - Component not found

YOU_MAY_NOT_BE_ABLE_TO_VISIT_THIS_PAGE_BECAUSE_OF:

AN_OUT_OF_DATE_BOOKMARK_FAVOURITE
A_SEARCH_ENGINE_THAT_HAS_AN_OUT_OF_DATE_LISTING_FOR_THIS_SITE
A_MIS_TYPED_ADDRESS
YOU_HAVE_NO_ACCESS_TO_THIS_PAGE
The requested resource was not found
An error has occurred while processing your request.

PLEASE_TRY_ONE_OF_THE_FOLLOWING_PAGES:

HOME_PAGE


IF_DIFFICULTIES_PERSIST__PLEASE_CONTACT_THE_SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR_OF_THIS_SITE
```

I would really appreciate some advice here with restoring access to it.

Comment: Check if you have one menupoint from main menu configured as default. Check: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=429&t=271082&start=30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forum can be accessed here:
http://www.yumping-amok.com/index.php?option=com_kunena

That suggests to me that the problem is with how you have created the menu item rather than with the forum.   Make sure the "menu item type" of the menu item with id 115 is of the kunena forum type.

If this does not help, you may want to expand your question to show a screengrab of what settings the menu item with id 115 has.

Comment: Thanks, setting the menu item type to "kunena forum" fixed the problem.